# NEED some guides on moving actors on stage libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

i am currently facing a problem where i try to move my actor by `touchdown` and i am confuse and did some error. I am trying to move my bucket to the left and right by dragging the actor. 
This is my code 
    package com.tcyzzz.savethesemester;

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;

import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.MoveByAction;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScreenViewport;
```

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

```
Stage stage;


@Override
public void create () {
    stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());//establish a stage for the game
    MyActor actor = new MyActor();
    stage.addActor(actor);
    stage.setKeyboardFocus(actor);
    actor.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            MoveByAction mba = new MoveByAction();
            mba.setAmount(5,0);
            stage.addAction(mba);
            return true;
        }
    });


    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);//handle user input


}

@Override
public void render () {

    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.draw();// call all sprites in actors class

}

@Override
public void dispose () {
    stage.dispose();//stage dispose

}
```

}

and my actors class

```
package com.tcyzzz.savethesemester;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;

import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Touchable;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.MoveByAction;
```

class MyActor extends Actor {
    Sprite sprite = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bucket.png")));

```
public MyActor(){
    setBounds(sprite.getX(),sprite.getY(),sprite.getWidth(),sprite.getHeight());
    setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);

}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    sprite.draw(batch);

    setBounds(sprite.getX(),sprite.getY(),sprite.getWidth(),sprite.getHeight());

}

@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta);
}
```

}

i need a clear instruction on how to move the bucket by dragging it using stage , actors .. thanks

Comment: You're mixing up your sprite positioning and actor positioning. Really you should use a TextureRegion instead of Sprite to avoid the redundancy (and bug-proneness)  of tracking position and color, etc. in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

@Tenfour04 is right
instead

```
setBounds(sprite.getX(),sprite.getY(),sprite.getWidth(),sprite.getHeight());
```

should use:

```
setBounds(getX(),getY(),sprite.getWidth(),sprite.getHeight());
```